# returning a non-directional path graph using python

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, graph

im having a hard time returning a non-directed graph in python i want the function to work as below

```
def pathGraph(4)
would output d ={0:[1], 1:[0, 2], 2:[1, 3], 3:[2]}.
```

I curently have this

```
def pathGraph(n):
  d = dict()
  for x in range(0,n):
    d[x]=list(range(x+1, n, n-1))
  return d

this returns {0:[1], 1:[2], 2:[3], 3:[]}
```

I notice that it's returning a directed graph and I want it to return a non-directed graph.

any help would be great thank you in advance!

Comment: Initialize the dictionary entries with empty lists. Then, given an edge (x,y) add connections in both directions: `d[x].append(y)` and `d[y].append(x)`.

Comment: @user3386109 am i doing this in the same for loop or do i need to add another for loop

Comment: In your loop, you set `d[x] = x+1`. So change that to `y = x+1`, and then do what I said in the first comment.

Comment: @user3386109, I get traceback errors when trying to do d[x].append(y)

Comment: tried working around it I can add y to the dictionary but I can't get the one before x, I've tried doing x-1 but that gives me a -1 for 0 and the x+1 gives me a 4 for 3

Comment: Yes, you do need to make sure that the `y` value is less than `n`.

Comment: @user3386109 - Thank you for your help, I have been led to a solution

Answer (score 0):

```
def pathGraph(n):
  d = dict()
  for x in range(0,n):
    for y in range(0,n):
      y = x+1
      if x-1 < 0:
        d[x] = [y]
      elif y >= n:
        d[x] = [x-1]
      else:
        d[x] = [x-1, y]
  return d
```

Comment: Please consider including a brief explanation of [how and why this solves the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/13138364). This will help future readers to better understand your solution. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/30205779)